Research in Machine Learning in the era of transformers
I'm a master's student in Machine Learning. I'm interested in pursuing research in the field, but I'm concerned about the recent advancements like ChatGPT, CLIP, and DiNO that require massive compute power for training. It makes me wonder: what can an average budget researcher do in this era of large transformer models that are expensive to train ?
